# Sticky keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard

I think the question has been asked before, but seems was left without an answer. 
What is the possible workaround to have different keyboard layouts for different windows? Are there any 3rd-party apps that can solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Open system settings and click Keyboard:

[image]

Then click the Layout tab and change the slider:

[image]

Comment: This slider does nothing

Comment: Unfortunately, this option doesn't work on Freya & Loki now. Follow the progress of fixes you can [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1444519), also you can [post bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/37962080-allow-different-layouts-for-individual-windows-does-not-work) for this bug.